# What will happen to my iPod Touch (4th Gen, iOS 6.1.6) if I upgrade to iCloud Drive?

Tags: icloud, ipod-touch

I currently have 3 Apple devices tied to my iCloud account:

- Macbook Air (2012) - just upgraded to Yosemite today
- iPad with Retina Display (4th edition) - iOS 8.0.2
- iPod Touch (4th Gen) - iOS 6.1.6

When I was asked in the Yosemite upgrade whether I would use iCloud Drive, the instructions warned that my iPod cannot be upgraded to a newer OS, and therefore would not be able to use iCloud Drive.

What does that mean? I currently use my iPod for little other than music, podcasts, and games.

Specifically, my question is, if I change to iCloud Drive, will my apps and games on my iPod no longer be able to save what files they save using legacy iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that if you upgrade to iCloud Drive, you won't be able to sync any game data with your iOS 8 devices. As an upgrade to iCloud Drive will no longer allow your older iOS 6 iPod to view or edit Documents in iCloud (which I assume includes game data).
Source: this [MacRumors forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1782664)